# c# outlook addin xml dynamic menu not populating

Tags: c#, xml, outlook

I am using ribbon xml to make a dynamic context menu and the menu appears, but is showing up inside the menu itself. I see "Dynamic Menu" and hover over the context menu button, but there are no contents.

My xml:

```
<contextMenus>
   <contextMenu idMso='ContextMenuCalendarItem'>
     <dynamicMenu id='MyDynamicMenu' label ='Dynamic Menu'getContent='GetMenuContent' />
   </contextMenu >
</contextMenus>
```

and my GetMenuContent method:

```
public string GetMenuContent(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
    {
        string xmlString = "<menu xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>";
        for (int i = 0; i < AddInDefs.thisProjectList.Count; i++)
        {
            xmlString = xmlString + "<button id='proj" + i + "' label='" +
                AddInDefs.thisProjectList[i].name.ToString() + "' onAction='displayMsg'/>";
        }
        xmlString = xmlString + "</menu>";
        return xmlString;
    }
```

I am thinking there is something wrong with the way I am making the GetMenuContent method. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by using:

```
StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder(@"<menu xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"" >");
        for (int i = 0; i < AddInDefs.thisProjectList.Count; i++)
        {
            xmlString.Append(@"<button id='proj" + i.ToString() + "' label='" +
                AddInDefs.thisProjectList[i].name.ToString() + "' onAction='displayMsg'/>");
        }
        xmlString.Append(@"</menu>");

        return xmlString.ToString();
```

and changing `Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI` to `Office.IRibbonControl control`